# Which is the best way to organize i18n resource keys?

Tags: internationalization

Which is best, organize i18n resource keys by component?

```
FILE_TAB_TITLE:    'Files'
FILE_FIELD_TITLE:  'File'
GROUP_TAB_TITLE:   'Group'
GROUP_FIELD_TITLE: 'Group'
SAVE_MENU_ITEM:    'Save'
SAVE_AS_MENU_ITEM: 'Save as...'
SAVE_BUTTON:       'Save'
```

Or by what they mean?

```
FILE:    'File'
FILES:   'Files'
GROUP:   'Group'
SAVE:    'Save'
SAVE_AS: 'Save as...'
```

Answer (score 2):

I think this is a convention more than a rule, so the answer might be "whatever seems more logical".

I've started to create my i18n resource keys, and I've adopted the following convention:

1. Header with a "title section", starting with #
2. Dot separated hierarchical notation
3. Keys organized alphabetically for easier access

Example:

```
#File access
file.field.title = File
file.field.subtitle = Click here
file.tab.title = Files

#User
user.name = First and last name
user.password = Password
user.username = Username
```

Answer (score 2):

I use terse, upper case versions of the English phrases. For example (JavaScript):

```
SAVE: "Save",
LOAD: "Load",
PLEASE_SELECT_ITEM: "Please select an item.",
PRESS_NEXT_TO_PROCEED: "Please press the Next button to proceed."
```

This way, the developer doesn't have to look up the content of a token to understand what it actually means.

I don't have redundant entries for items appearing in different places (e.g. like "Save" appearing in a menu versus on a button etc.) unless they appear in different modules that 
could potentially get translated individually.

Also, title/caption, prompt and error message tokens are organized into different files.

Answer (score 1):

I arrange mine by function in an hierarchy, such as

```
ui:
  choose: choose...
  save: save
  cancel: cancel
  preview: preview

season:
  summer: summer
  autumn: autumn
  winter: winter
  spring: spring

people: !!pl
  0: no people
  1: one person
  n: "%1 people"

is_are_people: !!pl
  0: are no people
  1: is one person
  n: "are %1 people"
```

and then in my helpers, routes or haml files (I use Sinatra mostly) I can refer to `Unicode::capitalize(t.ui.save)` in my 'Save' button and `"There #{t.is_are_people some_people.count}."` in my heading, etc.